# Routing practise with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, routes, symfony

I started using Ajax with Symfony2 and have some practise questions about it, especially the routing.

1. Over what HTTP-Method does Ajax send Requests (GET?) and which method is used to response (POST?)?
2. How should I design the routing for Ajax?
   Is there on big ajax-route where the controller checks out what the client want and answers or are there a couple of different routes. Or are there even hybrid controllers who handle HTML and JSON requests?

Answer (score 0):

You can send your request either by `POST` or `GET`. It is up to you.

There is nothing special with Ajax, neither different from normal routing design. Point your router to the controller you wish and handle request inside the function. In the end return data with JSON (which is my personal choice)

```
$return = json_encode($return);
return new Response($return, 200);
```

Comment: Hi, shouldn't there be more restrictions I should use?

Could I say that public Requests should be made by GET and more private ones with POST.


What is about the routing do I have one json-route which manages all  incoming Ajax requests or should I use seperated Controllers?

Comment: Since ajax is no more than a technique requesting without reloading a page, use it just like using normal POST or GET requests. Moreover, the number of routings and controllers depends on the variety of the requests, size of the project and so on.

Comment: You should use the new JsonReponse class for this exemple.